# How do I update the disabled attribute?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a button that I disabled via a boolean variable. The variable works on first load but when the variable is updated the disabled attribute stays. How do I update it so it gets removed?

My current code is like this:

```js
var isDisabled = true;

return (
    <>
        <button onClick={() => isDisabled = false}>Enable Second Button</button>
        <button disabled={isDisabled}>Second Button</button>    
    </>
)
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the disabled variable is set inside a state 
`const [isDisabled,setIsDisabled] = useState(false)`

if the state updates the node where the state is used will update too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using React useState instead of normal variables. Instead of:

```js
var isDisabled = true;

return (
    <>
        <button onClick={() => isDisabled = false}>Enable Second Button</button>
        <button disabled={isDisabled}>Second Button</button>    
    </>
)
```

I did

```js
const [isDisabled, setDisable] = useState(true);

return (
    <>
        <button onClick={() => setDisable(false)}>Enable Second Button</button>
        <button disabled={isDisabled}>Second Button</button>    
    </>
)
```